# Web API Model binding - Complex Parameter

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, model-binding, restful-url

I have a string received in query string

```
f[0][p]=zap&f[0][v][] = 110&f[0][v][]=500&f[1][p] = prih&f[1][v][] = 10000000&f[1][v][] = 30000000000
```

I try to catch it with `string[]` but it is always `null`. How to represent this parameter to Web API so it can serialize it?

I have a workaround with reading it for Uri as a string and then parse it but it is not good for unit testing and would like to update it.

Is it even possible with structure like this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this, maybe it can help someone.

I needed a class to represent the received object :

```
 public class Filter
 {
    private string p { get; set; }
    private string[] v { get; set; }
    private string cp { get; set; }
    private string[] cv { get; set; }
 }
```

And in method definition I needed:

```
public SubjectStats BusinessSubjects(string country, string start, string end, [FromUri] Filter[] f)
```

The key was to define object as `Filter[]` in method signature.